# Joomla 1.7.3 Errors with Xampp 1.7.7

Tags: installation, xampp, joomla1.7, php

I'm running windows 7, every time I try to install Joomla 1.7.3 on my xampp 1.7.7 setup to try and use Joomla, I get all these Strict Standard Errors:

```
Strict Standards: Static function JDatabase::test() should not be abstract in     C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\database\database.php on line 350

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 394

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396
```

I've looked through most of the questions and answers for my problem, and they all say the same thing. look at the php.ini file. Fair enough, I would love to. But when I head over to C:\xampp\php to find it, there are two files. php.ini-development and php.ini-production.

I have made the changes to the error reporting on both, restarted xampp, switched versions of xampp and joomla multiple times, nothing works.

I have also tried to modify the .htaccess file for joomla with:

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

and that doesn't work either.

If i create and run a phpinfo file to see exactly what file php is recognizing it tells me it's using C:\xampp\php\php.ini. I fail to understand how that is since there isn't just a plain jane php.ini file. I've looked. Numerous times.

Someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong, or what I don't understand about these multiple php.ini files that never change anything, and I can't seem to make work. I would just like to install Joomla so I can see how to use it for a possible quick intranet setup.

Answer (score 0):

Rename php.ini-development to php.ini. The php.ini-development file has the recommended settings for development and debugging while the php.ini-production file has warnings set to not display, etc.